# Google Maps (only show squares)

Tags: android

i am working in a application for showing google maps and I have some problem. In some projects that i found, it was shown grey squares in all of them, and I can't find my error.I also cheked my API code generated by my debug.keystore. Also I tried to change in the target's Android Project for API Google 2.3 and run or create a new android project and copy the code (also the result was the same).

In manifest I checked

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

In `main.xml`:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="AIzaSyD0CVBmcDp3HdXe0FNVykG7RnN0vYisZUw"
        />
```

In Java I confirmed the important

```
@Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<uses-library>` needs to be a child element of `<application>`, not a peer of `<uses-permission>`.

Beyond that, either:

- Your API key is wrong for your development machine, or
- Your device/emulator lacks Internet access (or, at least, access to the Google Maps servers)

Bear in mind that Maps V1 -- what you are using here -- is deprecated, and you supposedly cannot get new API keys for it. Please consider moving to [Maps V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/).

Comment: So the problem could be that the projects that I have been open are from Google Maps v1?

Comment: @RRUser: If you do not have a valid Maps V1 API key, you cannot write Maps V1 apps.

Comment: I have a MAps V2 API key. Can I use this key in a project for MAPS V1?

Comment: @RRUser: No, the keys are completely different. You would need to use Maps V2 with your Maps V2 key.